# How can I inject dependencies into an ELMAH custom ErrorLog?

Tags: c#, ninject, elmah

I have an ELMAH custom ErrorLog that uses an EF Code-First context to store the errors:-

```
class EntityFrameworkElmahErrorLog
{
    public EntityFrameworkElmahErrorLog(IDictionary config) : this() { }

    public override ErrorLogEntry GetError(string id)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            var intId = Int64.Parse(id, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var item = context.ErrorLog.Single(x => x.Id == intId);
            return new ErrorLogEntry(this, id, ErrorXml.DecodeString(item.Details));
        }
    }

    // etc.

}
```

The ErrorLog is wired up in the web.config:-

```
<errorLog type="MyProject.EntityFrameworkErrorLog, MyProject" />
```

I'm already using Ninject elsewhere in the project. I'd like to inject `MyContext` so that the `ErrorLog` isn't instantiating its own dependency, but I'm not having any luck finding a hook in the documentation. ELMAH appears to be instantiating the `ErrorLog` internally, so the only option I seem to have is using a `ServiceLocator` inside my custom `ErrorLog`, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Are there any better hooks available in ELMAH that I can use to inject ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Service location/Depdency injection extension point in ELMAH is the `ServiceCenter.Current` property where you can provide a delegate with the following signature:

```
public delegate IServiceProvider ServiceProviderQueryHandler(object context);
```

ELMAH will use the `System.IServiceProvider` returned by the `ServiceCenter.Current` to resolve the `ErrorLog` isntances.

So you need to do 3 things to setup it with Ninject (or any DI container)

1. Create your own `System.IServiceProvider` implementation with Ninject the `IKernel` interface already derives from from `System.IServiceProvider`, so it's done.
2. You need to register your `EntityFrameworkElmahErrorLog` in your container as an `ErrorLog` implemenation, because ELMAH will try to resolve an instance of `ErrorLog`.
3. Provide your delegate to `ServiceCenter.Current`

So you need something like the following in your `RegisterServices` method:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ErrorLog>().To<EntityFrameworkElmahErrorLog>();
    ServiceCenter.Current = (httpContext) => kernel;
}
```

Note: in in the `ServiceProviderQueryHandler` delegate you get the current `HttpContext` and with that you can fine tune how your expediencies are resolved.

You should also note that with this approach you will **lose the ability to configure your `ErrorLog` in your config file.**

ELMAH will always use the resolved instance from your container, because the built in `ServiceContainer` reads the config file what you override with your custom logic.